# Bootstrap Tabs not showing content when I use tal:repeat to display <li> elements in Pyramid Framework

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap, pyramid

I want to create dynamic tabs and their content in Pyramid using Bootstrap and Chameleon template engine for Python, but only the first tab remains activate despite of clicking on other tabs.
My HTML Code:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs responsive">
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tips">Tips</a></li>
    <li tal:repeat="key dict"><a data-toggle="tab"href="#${key}">${key}  </a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content responsive">
    <div tal:repeat="(keys,value) dict.iteritems()" id="${keys}" class="tab-pane fade">
    <p>${value}</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tips" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        <p>tips</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe its because you have hard-coded the `active` CSS class?

Comment: Thank you for replying Sir, the problem was because my keys has spaces between them. I removed the spaces and now its working fine.